# magento2 You cannot define a correlation name 'tdv' more than once

Tags: magento2.3

I want to load product. But it error You cannot define a correlation name 'tdv' more than once. If i load 1 product it working (setPageSize(1)). But when load more than 1 it error

This is my code file php

```
public function getLoadProduct()
{
    $productModel = $this->_productloader->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $productModel->setPageSize(1)->setCurPage(1)->load();
    return $productModel;
}
public function getOptionValue($optionId){
    if(isset($optionId)){
        $optionValue = $optionId;
        $optionFactory = $this->optionFactory->create();
        $optionFactory->load($optionValue);
        $attributeId = $optionFactory->getAttributeId();
        $optionData = $this->_attributeOptionCollection
                        ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                        ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                        ->setIdFilter($optionValue)
                        ->setStoreFilter()
                        ->load();
        return $optionData->getData()[0]['value'];
    }
    return "";
}
```

This is my code file phtml

```
 <?php $product = $this->getLoadProduct(); ?>
 <?php foreach($product as $item) : ?>
        <?php $val = $this->getOptionValue($item->getCommercersSelect()); ?>
        <li>
            <?php $image = $this->resize($item->getThumbnail(),240,300); ?>
            <?php echo '<img src="' . $image . '">';  ?> 
            <p><?php echo $item->getName(); ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $item->getPrice(); ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $item->getCommercersTraining(); ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $val; ?></p>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Please help me!